# Error HH801: Plugin @nomicfoundation/hardhat-toolbox requires the following dependencies to be installed

Tags: contract-development, blockchain, hardhat, hardhat-deploy, npm

It says to install the following dependencies but still while installing it will show error.

Please run:

```
npm install --save-dev "@ethersproject/providers@^5.4.7" "@nomicfoundation/hardhat-network-helpers@^1.0.0" "@nomicfoundation/hardhat-chai-matchers@^1.0.0" "@nomiclabs/hardhat-ethers@^2.0.0" "@nomiclabs/hardhat-etherscan@^3.0.0" "@types/chai@^4.2.0" "@types/mocha@^9.1.0" "@typechain/ethers-v5@^10.1.0" "@typechain/hardhat@^6.1.2" "chai@^4.2.0" "ethers@^5.4.7" "hardhat-gas-reporter@^1.0.8" "solidity-coverage@^0.8.1" "ts-node@>=8.0.0" "typechain@^8.1.0" "typescript@>=4.5.0"
```

Answer (score 0):

It is definitely related to your dependencies. Maybe you can update your question to show your `package.json` file.

See offical Hardhat docs here for errors (see HH801) here:

https://hardhat.org/hardhat-runner/docs/errors#internal-hardhat-errors

The docs say:

> **HH801: Plugin dependencies not installed**
>
> You are trying to use a plugin with unmet dependencies.
> Please follow Hardhat's instructions to resolve this.

If you still have problems after installing the dependencies, delete your `/node_modules` folder and the `package-lock.json` file, and re-install your packages.

Comment: I have done it but doenot seem to work

Comment: please update your question with your `package.json` and the console / error output you are getting

Answer (score 0):

I've been developing Solidity projects for almost a year now with Hardhat, and I've found that the easiest way is to use yarn for your package manager.

I install a bunch of deps with npm, then init a hardhat project, then do a `yarn install` after deleting package-lock.json and node_modules.

Answer (score 0):

I hope you would have resolved issue by now.

I encountered similar kind of error.
As the error asked to install the multiple packages. However, when you run command as it is, it gives error in specific packages. Make sure to exclude those packages which are giving error and install rest of the packages.

That's how it was resolved for me.